Android Tuya SDK gives an obscure "couldn't find DSO to load: libc.so"
I got an obscure error when trying to build my Android APP to speak with Smart Life/Tuya
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libc++_shared.so
caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libc.so
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:789)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:639)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:577)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:525)
at com.tuya.smart.security.load.TuyaLibraryLoader.securityLoadLibrary(TuyaLibraryLoader.java:17)
at com.tuya.smart.security.jni.JNICLibrary.doCommandNative(JNICLibrary.java:9)
at com.tuya.sdk.network.OooO00o.OooO00o(TuyaNetworkSecurityInit.java:1)
at com.tuya.smart.android.network.TuyaSmartNetWork.initialize(TuyaSmartNetWork.java:35)
at com.tuya.smart.sdk.TuyaSdk.initTuyaData(TuyaSdk.java:74)
at com.tuya.smart.sdk.TuyaSdk.init(TuyaSdk.java:146)
at com.tuya.smart.sdk.TuyaSdk.init(TuyaSdk.java:57)
[my code]

I'm using one of the latest free SDKs

implementation("com.tuya.smart:tuyasmart:3.26.5")


I've also enabled debug before login withoud success:

TuyaHomeSdk.setDebugMode(true);


I've double checked and:

libc++_shared.so is provided by the Tuya dependency
libc.so should be provided by the OS

Thus I don't really understand what's going on here: any hint on how to troubleshoot this in order to understand what's the issue
P.s.: I know that there are also more recent 3.36.5 libs but they require further signature and I want to be sure that the basic work before implementing all those "security measures" :-)

Thanks to official Tuya support in their forum I was able to understand that this is due to their toolkit including an old version of facebook's soloader, I've fixed by adding the following to the build.gradle of the app:
dependencies {
    // ... your other dependencies ...
    
    // Specify the newer version of SOLoader you want to use
    implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5'  // Replace with the latest version
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5'  // Replace with the latest version
        // You can also exclude the old version if needed
        // exclude group: 'com.facebook.soloader', module: 'soloader'
    }
}

